# Calculadora Tkinter no calcula de pies a metros

Tags: tkinter

y gracias estoy ejecutando este código. En ningún momento me genera error, solo que no me hace la conversión de pies a metros.(Podéis revisar y indicarme donde está mal?)

Habría 2 opciones para sacar el resultado, añadiendo el numérico y pulsando enter o con el botón calcular. Ninguno de los 2 funciona.

```
from tkinter import *

root =Tk()
root.title("Pies a metros")

def calcular(*args):
    try:
        value = float(pies.get())
        m = int(0.3048 * value * 10000 +0.5)/10000
        metros.set(m)
    except ValueError:
        metros.set("ERROR")

frame = Frame(root, pady=3, padx=12)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

pies = StringVar()
pies_input = Entry(frame, width=7, textvariable=pies)
pies_input.grid(column=1, row=0)

metros = StringVar()
Label(frame, textvariable=metros).grid(column=2, row=2)

Button(frame, text="Calcular", command=calcular).grid(column=2, row=2)

Label(frame, text="Pies").grid(column=0, row=0)
Label(frame, text="es igual a").grid(column=0, row=1)
Label(frame, text="metros").grid(column=2, row=1)

pies_input.focus()
root.bind("<Return>", calcular)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Necesito saber poque cuando ejecuto la aplicación con ese código, no me da el resultado.

Comment: Ahora te doy una respuesta, ya he encontrado tu problema, pero voy a ponerte el código como debería de ser...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu código debería de ser tal que así :

```
def calcular(*args):
    try:
        value = float(pies_input.get())
        m = int(0.3048 * value * 10000 +0.5)/10000
        resultado.config(text=m)
    except ValueError:
        resultado.config(text="ERROR")

frame = Frame(root, pady=3, padx=12)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

pies_input = Entry(frame, width=7)
pies_input.grid(column=1, row=0)

resultado = Label(frame, text = "")
resultado.place(x=53,y=22)

Button(frame, text="Calcular", command=calcular).grid(column=2, row=2)

Label(frame, text="Pies").grid(column=0, row=0)
Label(frame, text="es igual a").grid(column=0, row=1)
Label(frame, text="metros").grid(column=2, row=1)

pies_input.focus()
root.bind("<Return>", calcular)
root.mainloop()
```

Te recomiendo personalmente que no utilices `textvariable`, no es necesario.
El principal cambio que he hecho en tu código ha sido eliminar tus variables y crear el `Label resultado` que tiene una cadena vacía.

Una vez hecho esto, en tu función `calcular` se configura el texto de la `Label resultado` asignándole el valor de tu variable `m` ejecutando un `resultado.config(text=m)`, lo mismo en tu error : `resultado.config(text="ERROR")`.

Otro apunte personal, también considero que es mejor utilizar `.place()` que `.grid()`.

En `.place()` lo que hacemos es decirle donde estará situado nuestro Label o Entry o etc... Utilizando pixeles de pantalla. `x = PixelesHorizontal` y `y = PixelesVertical`

**Centrar aplicación en medio de la pantalla al abrirla :**
Te dejo este código por si algún día te sirve de utilidad.

```
window_width,window_height=710,555
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height= root.winfo_screenheight()
position_top = int(screen_height/2 - window_height/2)
position_right = int(screen_width/2 - window_width/2)
root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{position_right}+{position_top}')
```

`window_width,window_height=710,555` --> Asignas las dimensiones `ancho/alto`.

El resto del código son operaciones aritméticas para centrar la aplicación al centro de la pantalla.

También, en caso de que quisieras que no se redimensionara tu aplicación utiliza `root.resizable(0,0)`

Hay muchas mas cosas que saber sobre Tkinter, cualquier tipo de duda o aclaración escríbeme en los comentarios. Estaré encantado de responderte.

Un saludo!

Comment: Porfavor, cualquier duda que tengas sobre esto escribe un comentario y te voy respondiendo...

Comment: Si encuentras puntos de mejora, no sobra explicar EN la respuesta por qué el código resuelve el problema del OP (y de otros que quieran usar esta solución en el futuro).

Comment: @Alfabravo, estoy en ello, estoy editando la respuesta, he publicado ya la respuesta de esta forma para que tenga el resultado ya.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Intentaré esta tarde probarlo y te voy diciendo, gracias y de nuevo y te voy informando si todo queda OK.

Comment: Perfecto! Cualquier duda puedes escribir no te preocupes !

Comment: Hola, acabo de probar tu código y funciona a la perfección. Lo veo incluso más limpio.(Gracias y acabas de ayudar a un novato en este mundillo =) un saludo

Comment: No hay de que!!